# how to delete row items and fadeout in ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am facing another issue. i want to delete row via ajax and fadeout.

i have write below code. this is successfully deleted the row but do not fadeout.

```
var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
$.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "delete_order.php",
                       data: "id="+id,
                       success: function(){
                       row.find("td").fadeOut(1000, function(){ $(this).parent().remove();});


               }


     });
     return false;
```

Comment: Can you please post your html section.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you fadeOut the row itself?

```
row.fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/J79Ww/